# Produt of two nonnegative sequences being summable implies convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

For two scalar sequences $\{\alpha_k\}$ and $\{\beta_k\}$, if we know

1. Both sequences are nonnegative;
2. The sequence  $\{\alpha_k\}$ is non-increasing and non-summable, i.e., $\alpha_1\geq \alpha_{2}\geq\cdots\geq \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\alpha_k=0$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\alpha_k=\infty$;
3. The product of the two sequences is summable, i.e., $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\alpha_k\beta_k<\infty$

What can we say about the convergence of the sequence $\{\beta_k\}$? Does  $\{\beta_k\}$ has $0$ as its limit (limit inferior)? Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post some of your own efforts, as is required by the standard of this site.

Comment: You should replace $\alpha^k$ and $\beta^k$ by $\alpha_k$ and $\beta_k$ as I assume the sequences are not geometric series ....

Comment: Thanks Maksim, I just edited my expressions to avoid confusion.